# When user enters correct data on Appraisal page, display another tab called 'View Appraisals' on tab view in cshtml in ASP .NET Core (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

I have to create a book appraisal market where students can enter their book's data (title, ISBN, version, price). If the data is entered correctly, display data in another tab called 'View Appraisals'. Now, I have made this tab and everything works fine, but I have to add one more feature that would display the View Appraisals tab on all pages' tab, in the tab bar, once the user entered the correct data.

I will be adding all my code to create the program.

Model:

```
    namespace Lab4_Students4CheapTexts.Models
    {
        public class Textbooks
        {
            // declaring data members and getter/setter

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string title { get; set; }

            public int ISBN { get; set; }
            public int version { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int price { get; set; }

            // no parameter constructor
            public Textbooks()
            {
            }

            // full parameter constructor
            public Textbooks(string title, int ISBN, int version, int price)
            {
                this.title = title;
                this.ISBN = ISBN;
                this.version = version;
                this.price = price;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Your textbook: " + this.title + ", version: " + this.version + " was appraised at: " + this.price;
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    List<Textbooks> textbooksList = new List<Textbooks>();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Appraise()
    {
        return View();
    }       

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Appraise(Textbooks textbooks)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Your textbook: " +
                                        textbooks.title +
                                        ", Version: " +
                                        textbooks.version +
                                        " was priced at: " +
                                        textbooks.price;

                return View("view_appraisals", textbooks);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Bad");
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Views:

INDEX.CSHTML

```
<article id="box">
    <header>
        <h1>Students4CheapTexts</h1>
        <img src="~/Images/logo.png"
             alt="Logo"
             height="50"
             width="50" />
    </header>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href=".~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>
        index
    </p>
  </article>
```

APPRAISE.CSHTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
</ul>

<form action="~/Home/Appraise" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="title">Textbook Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="make" name="title" placeholder="" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="isbn">Textbook ISBN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn" placeholder="" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="version">Textbook Version:</label>
        <input type="text" id="version" name="version" placeholder="" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="originalPrice">Original Purchase Price:</label>
        <input type="text"
               id="originalPrice"
               name="originalPrice"
               placeholder="" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="condition">Condition:</label>
        <select name="condition" id="condition">
            <option value="likeNew">Like New</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <br />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Appraise" />
</form>
```

VIEW_APPRAISALS.CSHTML

```
<header>
    <h1>All Entered Books List</h1>
    <img src="~/Images/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="50" width="50" />
</header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="~/Home/view_appraisals">View Appraisals</a></li>


</ul>

<h3> The model car could not be created because you have entered something incorrectly.</h3>
```

BAD.CSHTML

```
<header>
    <h1>Incorrect input</h1>
    <img src="~/Images/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="50" width="50" />
</header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
    

</ul>

<h3> The model car could not be created because you have entered something incorrectly.</h3>
```

CSS for all my HTML pages:

```
/* Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
   for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets. */

    a.navbar-brand {
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: center;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    /* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
    a {
        color: #0366d6;
    }

    .btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #1b6ec2;
        border-color: #1861ac;
    }

    .nav-pills .nav-link.active,
    .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #1b6ec2;
        border-color: #1861ac;
    }

    /* Sticky footer styles
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    html {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        html {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }

    .border-top {
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    .border-bottom {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }

    .box-shadow {
        box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    button.accept-policy {
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: inherit;
    }

    /* Sticky footer styles
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
    }

    html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    body {
        /* Margin bottom by footer height */
        margin: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
    }

    ul {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px 0;
        background: #aaa;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

        ul li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

            ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #000;
                padding: 20px 30px;
                font-size: large;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

                ul li a.active {
                    background: #eee;
                }

    p {
        width: 40vw;
        text-align: justify;
        margin: auto;
        line-height: 35px;
    }

    article.box {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    form {
        border: 1px dotted #000;
        width: 60vw;
        padding: 20px 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

        form div {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

            form div input {
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }

        form input[type=submit] {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }

    header h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Just to be sure but do you want to show VIEW_APPRAISALS.CSHTML in every tab?

Comment: yes. All the cshtml pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps put the Partial Tag Helper on each of the cshtml pages you want to include in any of your tabs.

Index.cshtml

```
<article id="box">
<header>
    <h1>Students4CheapTexts</h1>
    <img src="~/Images/logo.png"
         alt="Logo"
         height="50"
         width="50" />
</header>

<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href=".~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
</ul>

<p>
    Here is stuff from indes page and below is the stuff from View_Appraisals. You can include it anywhere.
    <hr />
    <partial name="VIEW_APPRAISALS">
</p>
```

Comment: Adding partial helps to show the View Appraisal page, but it was not adding appraised data on the view appraisal page. BTW, it does show the View Appraisal page. Thank you gardavalur.

Answer (score 0):

> If the data is entered correctly, display data in another tab called
> 'View Appraisals'. Now, I have made this tab and everything works
> fine, but I have to add one more feature that would display the View
> Appraisals tab on all pages' tab, in the tab bar, once the user
> entered the correct data.

You could try to use the [_layout page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to display the tab bar navigation link, code like this:

_layout.cshtml: (check the navbar)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">WebApplication1</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a  class="nav-link text-dark" href ="~/Home/view_appraisals">View Appraisals</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>

        <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
            <div class="container">
                &copy; 2020 - WebApplication1 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then, in other views, there is no need to add navigation link, just using the layout page, code like this:

Index.cshtml:

```
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

        <article id="box"> 
        <p>
            index Page
        </p>
      </article>
```

Code in the Appraise.cshtml page:

```
    <h1>Appraise</h1>

    @*<ul>
        <li><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="~/Home/Appraise">Appraise</a></li>
    </ul>*@

    <form action="~/Home/Appraise" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="title">Textbook Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="make" name="title" placeholder="" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="isbn">Textbook ISBN:</label>
            <input type="text" id="isbn" name="isbn" placeholder="" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="version">Textbook Version:</label>
            <input type="text" id="version" name="version" placeholder="" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="originalPrice">Original Purchase Price:</label>
            <input type="text"
                   id="originalPrice"
                   name="originalPrice"
                   placeholder="" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="condition">Condition:</label>
            <select name="condition" id="condition">
                <option value="likeNew">Like New</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <br />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Appraise" />
    </form>
```

Code in the view_appraisals view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Textbooks> 
    <table class="table">
          @* list all model *@
    </table>
```

In the controller, I will use the session to store the correct data. After submitting the correct data, store the data into session, then, get data from the session and display all the records. You could also store them into the database. (To use session in asp.net core, check [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state), then configure session state and add the SessionExtensions (uses to store complex object)).

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }        

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Appraise()
    { 
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Appraise(Textbooks textbooks)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your textbook: " +
                                    textbooks.title +
                                    ", Version: " +
                                    textbooks.version +
                                    " was priced at: " +
                                    textbooks.price;
            //check if session exist and the the data.
            if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks") != null)
            {
                textbooksList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks");
            }

            textbooksList.Add(textbooks);
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks", textbooksList);
            // ViewData["isDisplay"] = true;
            return View("view_appraisals", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Bad");
        }
    }

    public IActionResult view_appraisals()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks") == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            textbooksList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks");  
        }

        if (textbooksList.Count>0)
        {
           // ViewData["isDisplay"] = true;
            return View("view_appraisals", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("bad");
        }
    }
```

The result like this: (if the entered data correct, it will directly redirect to the view_appraisal page)

[image]

You might want to hide the "View Appraisals" navigation link if there have no data, and, if there has records, display the "View Appraisals" navigation link. If that is the case, try to modify the navigation code (in the _layout.cshtml) as below:

```
                    @{ 
                        var isdisplay = "none";  //default value, hidden the View Appraisals link.
                        if (ViewData["isDisplay"] != null)
                        {
                            isdisplay = "block";
                        }
                    }
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" style="display:@isdisplay" href ="~/Home/view_appraisals">View Appraisals</a>
                    </li>
```

Then, if you want to show the link, in the controller, set a value for "ViewData["isDisplay"]", code like this:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }        

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Appraise()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks") != null)
        {
            ViewData["isDisplay"] = true;
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Appraise(Textbooks textbooks)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your textbook: " +
                                    textbooks.title +
                                    ", Version: " +
                                    textbooks.version +
                                    " was priced at: " +
                                    textbooks.price;

            if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks") != null)
            {
                textbooksList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks");
            }

            textbooksList.Add(textbooks);
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks", textbooksList);
            ViewData["isDisplay"] = true;
            return View("view_appraisals", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Bad");
        }
    }

    public IActionResult view_appraisals()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks") == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            textbooksList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Textbooks>>("textbooks");  
        }

        if (textbooksList.Count>0)
        {
            ViewData["isDisplay"] = true;
            return View("view_appraisals", textbooksList);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("bad");
        }
    }
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, @Zhi Lv. It helped me with a better understanding. I did it the wrong way.